# (CoreData Project) To avoid a crash I have to synthesize NSFetchedResultsController manually - Why?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

When I don't `synthesize` the `NSFetchedResultsController` `property` manually my app crashes.

**Crash Log:**

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:1070
2013-03-06 15:09:15.667 Staff Manager[6673:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 2 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

When I `synthesize` it as follow all works as expected:

```
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;
```

Can you explain?

My state of knowledge is that Xcode's compiler does this for me.

**Xcode Version: 4.6
Deployment Target: 6.1**

**App crashes in this method (last line)**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        Person *personToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:personToDelete];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self performFetch];

        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you override the getter/setter for this property? Also, do you send any messages to `_fetchedResultsController` in your code?

Comment: No, I did not overwrite any getter/setter methods for the controller. Only synthesized the property. Please see updated post, I have added the method where the app crashes. You can see where I call `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can say is when you use create a project from xcode with an already created nsfetchresultscontroller, the fetchresultscontrollerdelegate is created in a way it already perform the deleteRowsAtIndexPaths when you delete a displayed managedobject it automatically delete the corresponding tableview cell

you should only keep the deleteObject part

```
Person *personToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:personToDelete];
[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

Comment: The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 2 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).' => the tableview receive the instruction to delete two rows (or to be more precise, two instructions to delete one row, the first is done by the nsfetchresultscontroller delegate and the second is yours)